# Php form to email attachment

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment

file attachment is not working with this mentioned code. Is there any solution for this ? what is the error in this code for attach file? i need to be attach all type of extn files.

```
<?php

$c_name=$_POST['c_name'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$comp_name=$_POST['comp_name'];
$add_1=$_POST['add_1'];
$add_2=$_POST['add_2'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state_name=$_POST['state_name'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$fax=$_POST['fax'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$hear=$_POST['hear'];
$upload_file=$_POST['upload_file'];



    $body .= "Contact Name: " . $c_name . "\n"; 
    $body .= "Title: " . $title . "\n"; 
    $body .= "Company Name: " . $comp_name . "\n"; 
    $body .= "Address 1: " . $add_1 . "\n";
    $body .= "Address 2: " . $add_2 . "\n";
    $body .= "City: " . $city . "\n";
    $body .= "State/Province: " . $state_name . "\n";
    $body .= "Zip Code: " . $zip . "\n";
    $body .= "Phone: " . $phone . "\n";
    $body .= "Fax: " . $fax . "\n";
    $body .= "E-mail: " . $email . "\n";
    $body .= "Message: " . $message . "\n";
    $body .= "Hear about us from:" . $hear . "\n"; 
    $file .= "". $upload_file . "\n";


    //replace with your email
    mail("example@example.com","New email",$body,$file); 


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get PHPMailer class from [PHPMailer Script](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and use as well as you want :)